# $Var(X_1 X_2)=Var(X_1) Var(X_2)$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, variance

Let : $X_1$ and $X_2$ two independent variables, square-integrable et non constant.

At which necessary and sufficient condition, do we have $ Var(X_1 X_2)= Var(X_1) Var(X_2)$ ?

---

Attempt :
$V(Z)= V( E(Z|X_1) ) + E(V(Z|X_1))$ if $Z$ is a random variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$var(X_1 X_2) = E(var(X_1 X_2|X_2))+var(E(X_1 X_2 | X_2)\\
=E(X_2^2 var(X_1)) + var(X_2 E(X_1))\\
= var(X_1) (E(X_2)^2 + var(X_2)) + E(X_1)^2 var(X_2)\\
= var(X_1) var(X_2) + E(X_2)^2 var(X_1) + E(X_1)^2 var(X_2)$$

Since $X_1, X_2$ are not constants then we must have $E(X_1)=E(X_2)=0$ which is necessary and sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

With $Z=X_1 X_2$ your attempt leads to
\begin{align}
V(X_1 X_2)
&= V(X_1 E[X_2 \mid X_1]) + E[X_1^2 V(X_2 \mid X_1)]
\\
&= E[X_2]^2 V(X_1) + V(X_2) E[X_1^2]
\\
&= V(X_1)V(X_2) + V(X_1)E[X_2]^2 + V(X_2) E[X_1]^2
\end{align}